# MyBatis dynamic ResultMap. How to return list of different POJO objects?

Tags: java, mapping, mybatis

MyBatis mapping issue.

Suppose we have a table USERS

```
CREATE TABLE USERS(
   USER_ID int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   LOGIN varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   EMAIL varchar(255),
   SALARY int(10),
   AVG_SCORE int(10),
   PRIMARY KEY ( USER_ID )
);
```

And there are 3 POJO classes -

```
public class User {
    private Long id;
    private String login;
    private String email;

...getters/setters
}
```

and two more classes extending User

```
public class Student extends User {
    private Integer score;
...getters/setters
}

public class Teacher extends User {
    private Integer salary;
...getters/setters
}
```

and a mapper (I use XML but actually it does not matter).

```
<select id="selectAll" resultMap="<dynamicResultMapHere>">
    SELECT * FROM USERS
    <some conditions here>
</select>
```

I would like to get `List<Teacher>` or `List<Student>` instances depending on whether SALARY column is empty or not.

How to add the dynamic results filling?

Actually the case is more complicated. I somehow need to return different results depending on query parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [documentation](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html) about **discriminator**.
It will require a `resultMap` for specific fields of `Student` and `Teacher` referenced by a `resultMap` for `User` (for common fields) and a `<discriminator>` part.

A pseudo column will likely be required:

```
SELECT (CASE WHERE salary IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) AS userType
```

and then

```
<discriminator javaType="int" column="userType">
    <case value="1" resultMap="studentResultMap" />
    <case value="2" resultMap="teacherResultMap" />
</discriminator>
```

Comment: Is it possible to have dynamic discriminator? I am trying to add a generic approach https://github.com/StanislavLapitsky/mybatis-star-dao Kind of SelectAll which accepts table name and provides Entity classes on fly. It means I have no fixe amount of entity to enlist them in the `discriminator` block. +1 anyway. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: Looks like you are tying to make an ORM with Mybatis while Mybatis is SQL mapper, not an ORM. Any JPA framework would allow bringing a closer answer to what you are trying to achieve: just having java entities annotated to map tables then CRUD operation are straight forward.

Comment: I am trying to have both ORM and SQL mapper. I met some projects where both hibernate and MyBatis are used, Would be nice to merge them somehow.

Comment: indeed, you want best from both worlds, but I guess this is not so obvious otherwise it  would have already been done.